# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'attributes')

Tags: attributes, typeerror

this error keeps on popping but after refresh it goes away.

```
import { useState, useContext } from "react";

import RelatedProducts from "./RelatedProducts/RelatedProducts";
import {
  FaFacebookF,
  FaTwitter,
  FaInstagram,
  FaLinkedinIn,
  FaCartPlus,
} from "react-icons/fa";
import prod from "../../assets/products/collection/H1.png";
import "./SingleProduct.scss";
import useFetch from "../../hooks/useFetch";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { Context } from "../../utils/context";
const SingleProduct = () => {
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(1);
  const { id } = useParams();
  const { data } = useFetch(`/api/products?populate=*&[filters][id]=${id}`);
  const { handleAddToCart } = useContext(Context);
  const increment = () => {
    setQuantity((prevState) => prevState + 1);
  };
  const decrement = () => {
    setQuantity((prevState) => {
      if (prevState === 1) return 1;
      return prevState - 1;
    });
  };
  if (!data) return;
  const product = data.data[0].attributes;
  return (
    <div className='single-product-main-content'>
      <div className='layout'>
        <div className='single-product-page'>
          <div className='left'>
            <img
              src={
                process.env.REACT_APP_DEV_URL +
                product.img.data[0].attributes.url
              }
              alt=''
            />
          </div>
          <div className='right'>
            <span className='name'>{product.title}</span>
            <span className='price'>&#8377;{product.price}</span>
            <span className='disc'>{product.desc}</span>
            <div className='cart-buttons'>
              <div className='quantity-buttons'>
                <span onClick={decrement}>-</span>
                <span>{quantity}</span>
                <span onClick={increment}>+</span>
              </div>
              <button
                className='add-to-cart-button'
                onClick={() => {
                  handleAddToCart(data.data[0], quantity);
                  setQuantity(1);
                }}
              >
                <FaCartPlus size={20} />
                ADD TO CART
              </button>
            </div>
            <span className='divider' />
            <div className='info-item'>
              <span className='text-bold'>
                Category: {""}
                <span>{product.categories.data[0].attributes.title}</span>
              </span>
              <span className='text-bold'>
                Share:
                <span className='social-icons'>
                  <FaFacebookF size={16} />
                  <FaTwitter size={16} />
                  <FaInstagram size={16} />
                  <FaLinkedinIn size={16} />
                  <FaFacebookF size={16} />
                </span>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <RelatedProducts
          productId={id}
          categoryId={product.categories.data[0].id}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SingleProduct;
```

I was doing product details related products api integration
I am new to react js
i keep on getting this error but when i restart or refresh this error goes away.
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'attributes')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'attributes')

Comment: There are three places in the code where you're reading a property called `attributes` from an object.  Which one is producing the error?  The error is telling you that the object is `undefined`.  In all three cases you're reading an array element from a parent object.  When the error occurs, what is the observed value of that parent object?  Why do you expect the array to have at least one element, when the error indicates that it does not?